# How to Implement h265 format video in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

In flutter, How to implement h265 file format videos in flutter, I have tried with better_player package, but i seems like not supporting h265 format, So does any know how to implement this one or is anyone Implemented in this feature , or supporting packahe is available?
please comment, Your comment would be great helpful, i am stucking this one,

Comment: Did you tried VLC package? :- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to implement H.265 video in Flutter.

add this dependancy in your project:- [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

This is a example of **H.265** format video player

```
class VideoPlayerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _VideoPlayerScreenState createState() => _VideoPlayerScreenState();
}

class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      'H265 VIDEO URL',
    )..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
  }

@override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _controller.value.isInitialized
        ? AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
          )
        : CircularProgressIndicator();
  }
```